# Is POS application required to PCI DSS compliant

Tags: pci-dss

I am eftPOS software Engineer, develop bank financial applications. Applications are MTIP, ADVT and CUP certified. A/c to PCI DSS, are we also need to compliant our app with PCI. I ask this question b/c POS stores credit card information untill settlement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If credit credit card is stored, even though temporarily, application needs to comply withe PCI DSS